# how to create a symbolic link that works relative to the working directory

Tags: 14.04, command-line, symbolic-link

consider the following :

```
x/
    ph/
        file1.txt -> ./../file1.txt
    file1.txt
y/
    ph/ -> /x/ph/ (this is full absolute path of x/ph)
    file1.txt
```

`/y/ph` is a symlink for `ph` folder in `x`. and `file1.txt`is a relative symlinks.

it works correctly in `x` folder however if you open 
`/y/ph/file1.txt` instead of opening `/y/file1.txt` it opens `/x/file1.txt`

the goal here is to have the same directory (lets say a program) in multiple places with different config files without having to have multiple copies of the program.

according to `ln`'s help

> Symbolic links can hold arbitrary text; if later resolved, a relative link is interpreted in relation to its parent directory.

so relative links are relative to the actual folder's path not the current working directory. **the question is :** is there any workarounds for this ?

test case:

```
mkdir x y x/ph
echo x1 > ./x/file1.txt
echo y1 > ./y/file1.txt
ln -s $(pwd)/x/ph ./y/ph
cd ./x/ph
ln -s ./../file1.txt
cd ../..
cat ./x/ph/file1.txt
cat ./y/ph/file1.txt
```

expected result is `x1 y1` but you get `x1 x1`

**Edit:**

to make the question clearer, run the test case in an empty folder.
and try the following commands in the folder:

```
bor@borpc:~/tmp$ readlink -f ./x/ph/file.txt
/home/bor/tmp/x/ph/file.txt
bor@borpc:~/tmp$ readlink -f ./y/ph/file.txt
/home/bor/tmp/x/ph/file.txt
--------------^
```

i want that `x` there to be `y`. that is to make the relative symlink resolve based on `pwd` (current working directory or path used to access it) rather than the actual path of the actual file.

if it is possible how would one achieve such behavior.

Comment: I am confused also. I think the expected answer is x1 x1 which is what you get.

Comment: @DougSmythies i know that linux gives x1 x1 and it is according to the specifications . the question is how to get x1 y1 ?

Comment: @DougSmythies i want the same link to refer to different files depending on the path used to access it.

Comment: This is very ironic that you use `x` and `y` names for your folders. Because there is known problem called [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you please explain **Why** you want it, and also add more description what exactly do you want. In other words explain what problem are you trying to solve.

Comment: @c0rp i've explained in the question that the goal is to remove need for copying an application again in order to have 2 instances of it running. the actual case is a php website including thousands of files with over 500MB size , that two instances of it differ only in 2 files (config.php).

Comment: @c0rp the name does not have to be x and y , it was `/home/username/domains/domain1/public_html` and `domain2` i've renamed for simplicity

Comment: @c0rp i see your point about the xy problem. there sure exists other ways to solve the problem and we did in fact solve it some other way , but since i was the one that suggested this method and it didn't work , i wanted to know if it is possible at all (even with a workaround) or not.

Comment: I don't fully understand how you want to have different content of files, but do not want to have different copies of files. Could you explain what exactly configs you are mastering. May be there is another, cleaner way to solve your problem. What is name of program that this configs belongs to (`bash`, `git`, `tomcat`, `nginx`, etc..)

Comment: @c0rp i've edited the answer. consider a wordpress installation , there is a config.php file with database connection information and an upload folder , other than these two everything else is exactly the same. i wanted to put these two files on directory up from the public_html , and make public_html itself a symlink to a shared folder which had relative symlinks for these specific files. but right now the question is more general , how to make a single symlink resolve differently depending on the path used to access it.

Comment: So, you can make all other files in those folders to be symlinks, except this `config.php`.

Comment: yeah but that would make it extremely difficult to update the shared installation , you would have to recreate all instances. but if it was the way i am trying to achieve there would only be one symlink to a folder , no matter if files were added or deleted or modified all instances would have the changes without any modification.

Comment: @Bor691, you don't have to update all instances, they are will be links, if you update one file all links also would be updated automatically. A few more question: Why you are copying them on same machine? Why don't you make those "shared" files really be shared, not just copied and linked outside the code? Also if you know `php` you can rewrite configs and read those settings from some file depending on working_dir.

Comment: @c0rp i'm thankful that you are trying to help me find an alternative solution , however if you've read my fifth comment i notified you that we have managed to solve the problem using an alternate method. i wanted to know if there is a way to force symbolic links to behave this way. if you think it is impossible just say so.

Comment: +1, I understand what the OP is trying to do. It may be an XY problem, there's other solutions, but the answer is "no, not with symlinks but you can with bind mounts"

Comment: @Josh If you post an answer with example commands to achieve this with bind mounts I will accept it as the answer. Thanks for taking the time to read the question even if the project I needed this for has been abandoned 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused. You might make a symbolic link beginning at root directory (I mean `/`). For example,

```
ln -s /root/try/d s

ls -l  
total 0  

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  0 Apr 24 16:15 d  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Apr 24 16:18 s -> /root/try/d
```

Comment: the link on ./y/ph is using the full path , i didn't write that to make the test case usable in any folder , but $(pwd) returns the full path to currect directory

Comment: Don't use `./y/ph` instead of full path.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with symlinks. Symlinks don't work that way. A relative symlink will be relative to the link file itself, not to the path you're in.

You can, however, achieve something similar with [a bind mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount):

```
[you@example example]$ mkdir x y x/ph y/ph
[you@example example]$ echo x1 > ./x/file1.txt
[you@example example]$ echo y1 > ./y/file1.txt
[you@example example]$ sudo mount --bind ./x/ph ./y/ph
[you@example example]$ cd ./x/ph
[you@example ph]$ ln -s ../file1.txt
[you@example ph]$ cd ../..
[you@example example]$ cat ./x/ph/file1.txt
x1
[you@example example]$ cat ./y/ph/file1.txt
y1
```